# can UTC replace Lamport logical clocks?

Tags: distributed-systems, clocks

if UTC is universal, what drawbacks does it have in using it in a distributed system to coordinate events or use it as a global objective reference clock?

isn't it right to just use UTC to timestamp every message to order messages without using lamport logical clocks!

Comment: If you can guarantee a bound on the desynchronization of the clocks, then you can indeed tell if events are "simultaneous", else what is the ordering.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but if they use UTC they don't have to synchronize their clocks, they will request the timestamp from the central server, get that timestamp add the delay (if its synchronous network) and now you have consensus.

Comment: You confuse UTC which is a time reference convention, and clock synchronization on a network. Perfect synchronization is never possible, and using UTC does not help.

Comment: Even if you have perfect synchronization of clocks in UTC, using UTC timestamp  only may lead to "overordering" or wrong logical ordering. For example, event EA at process A happened at UTC TA and event EB at process B happened at UTC TB, where TA is earlier than TB. However, all effects of EA reach process B after TB, if any of them does reach process B at all. Then from the point of view of process B, it should be better to consider EA happens after EB logically. Locally, the logical order may be easier to operate and more significant for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In a distributed system, achieving perfect time synchronization among all nodes is often impossible.  Lamport logical clocks are one way to deal with this problem.

I presume that by "use UTC to timestamp" you are assuming that you will use a timestamp.  The problem is that machines' clocks usually aren't perfectly synchronized, so machine A might give a timestamp of 5:00:00.00 and machine B might give a timestamp of 5:00:00.13, but the event on B might actually have happened first even though the timestamp appears to be later, because B's clock isn't synchronized to A's clock.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_clock.

Comment: but if they use UTC they don't have to synchronize their clocks, they will request the timestamp from the central server, get that timestamp add the delay (if its synchronous network) and now you have consensus.

Comment: @ezio, I've already told you the reason: in most systems, there is no way to achieve perfect time synchronization.  No matter how many times you use the word "UTC", you can't assume all nodes have perfect time synchronization.  To start to get a sense of why, you might ponder how you would ensure perfect time synchronization in a large distributed system, and how you will make it resilient to failures (loss of network connectivity, individual nodes being down).

Comment: Or, to put it another way: in most systems, "UTC" is a fiction that can't be measured exactly.  I apologize for my failures in communication -- I can see I'm probably not explaining clearly.

Comment: You have two problems: One, if you have one event in London and one in Los Angeles, "which one happened first" is not well defined (Thank you Mr. Einstein. You got us into a fine mess). Two, even if it was well defined in principle, there will be events so close together that you can't determine which one happened first. Instead, we use a method that numbers events #1, #2, #3, ..., with a good attempt to make the order consistent with UTC, but what we use is those numbers, not actual UTC.

Comment: @D.W. i guess i understand the main flaw in my reasoning, just because i timestamp some event with UTC doesn't mean it objectively is the time that event happened, because the event is created before the timestamp therefore multiple events are seen as concurrent with this one because there is no way to tell which is first before the timestamp, could you please add this to your answer so that i mark it as correct, thank you

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks for the clarification

Comment: @ezio, I don't think the problem is that the event is created before the timestamp; I'm guessing the gap between those two can be made arbitrarily small, so I think that issue is surmountable.  I think the insurmountable problem is the lack of clock synchronization.

Comment: @D.W. it always could be arbitrarily small, but objectively it is meaningless to make it small and that's the real problem